# Add a remote location through a login machine

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, remote, sftp

I have my Ubuntu laptop (call it A) and I want to add a computer (call it B) to the "Other locations" tab of nautilus. The problem is that I can not ssh directly from A to B, but through a login machine (call it L). So when I need to access the computer B, I do ssh L and then ssh B. Is there a way to add B to the "Other locations" tab of laptop A? Doing it for L is pretty much straightforward using sftp and the address but I cannot figure out how to do it for B. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a config entry in `.ssh/config` for your jump host, using [`ProxyJump`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html)

```
### The Bastion Host
Host bastion-host-nickname
  HostName bastion-hostname

### The Remote Host
Host remote-host-nickname
  HostName remote-hostname
  ProxyJump bastion-host-nickname
```

Put the IPs/Domain names in the `Hostname` fields and then add `sftp://remote-host-nickname` to other hosts